# How to add run parameters to a C#

Tags: c#, console-application

Its really really hard to explain what i am trying to do, so i will just explain what is the program i am trying to build.

I am building a Console App in C#.

I need to run it every day at 6:00. I have already built the timer for it, but i need it to get parameter with a "Name" like when you run it into PowerShell.  I need to do something like that:

```
.\run.exe Name
```

which in my program I need the name in a string, and write with it.. and use it ofc. 
i will like to know how to add it, so i can do even:

```
.\run.exe Name Name2 Name3
```

Thanks again everyone, you are helping me here alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Console App entry point may look like

```
public static void Main(string[] args) { }
```

the args array contains all parameters you have passed via command line. The different elements are those that were separated by space.

So if you call your prog like `prog.exe Name`, **args[0]** will contain the value **"Name"**. `args.Length` will have the value 1 . If you call `prog.exe Name X`, `args.Length` will be 2 and `args[1]` will be "X".

Comment: here's an article on how to work with arrays:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: leave it. Thanks again :) i found it. THANKSKKKSS!

Comment: args[whatever index name is].

Answer (score 0):

What you want is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

```
if (args.Length == 0)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric argument.");
    return 1;
}
else if(args.Length == 1)
{
//do stuff here
}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // ... use args[] to get at your arguments...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem. The arguments you supply are available. Try this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
        }
     }
```

if you want name, you might want to do something like

```
program.exe  /name=name /brand=brand /three=somethingelse
```

and parse the args for the /name=

This way you have more control over the arguments and the user can provide them in random order.

Comment: When parsing the arguments, is the entire value of the argument args[0] "/name=name" (in the 1st parameter in your example)?  So I have to split the string and confirm the left side is the name of the parameter and the right is a valid value?